# How to read Python comprehension with two expressions?

Tags: python

I do not quite understand **how to read** the following comprehension, even though I know what it does:

```
>>> matrix=[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
>>> [x for row in matrix for x in row]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

So, how does this comprehension translate into natural language? I'm not sure because if I try to divide this expression into two parts `x for row in matrix` and `for x in row` they all become nonesense in the context of the task.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just add a new line between `for`s, and make them regular for loops:

```
for row in matrix:
    for x in row:
        print x
```

The order is like the order of such regular loops, as the nested loops should be write outer.

```
[x for row in matrix for x in row for t in x]
   (level 1) --->  (level 2) ---> (level 3)
           ---> nested loops
```

Comment: Hm. Thanks! Now it makes sense.

Comment: I wish, I could accept all answers, but your answer was first that treated 2D case. Thanks for this explanation!

Comment: But why did they do it this way? I've been using python a lot for last 3-4 years and I still find writing multiple `for`'s a in list comprehension to be somewhat confusing and usually `chain` (\flattern) nested list comprehensions, because (imho) that is somewhat more explicit, so I can read it as if it is getting executed "from the outside, towards the inside" (as most of other things do, like function composition).

Comment: @BenUsman I thinks if we consider another ways we will realize that this is the most clear way to do that, because the other ways are most confusing. Just suppose that if they write the loops from inside to outside or write them interleave :-)

Answer (score 3):

The best way to read list comprehension is to read them as reverse order for loop:

```
>>> l=[1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> [i*2 for i in l]
[2, 4, 6, 8]
```

is equivalent to:

```
>>> new_list=[]
>>> for i in l:
...    new_list+=[i*2]
... 
>>> print(new_list)
[2, 4, 6, 8]
```

As for 2d lists:

```
>>> matrix=[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
>>> [col for row in matrix for col in row]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

is equivalent to:

```
>>> new_list=[]
>>> for row in matrix:
...     for col in row:
...         new_list+=[col]
... 
>>> print(new_list)
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

Comment: Your solution is neat and what I would prefer +1

Answer (score 2):

It represents a two-level deep `for` loop. When you break it down:

```
[ x | for row in matrix | for x in row ]
```

You'll see, leftmost part is the innermost expression and the rest is the nested loops:

```
result = []
for row in matrix:
    for x in row:
        result.append(x)
```